# Updating running .exe file c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I've developped an application that imports various stuff to our database. Users will be using it by running shortcut to our internal application server. Because working hours vary, I need to be able to change the .exe file while someone is using it. 
The way my coworkers suggested is this:

1.Save in xml / ini file name of the file which should be run.

2.Copy new .exe, f.e import_2.exe to target location.

3.Simply execute the .exe file from the ini file.

I stopped at point 3. How do I change the target file ? Application.ExecutablePath cannot be changed.

@EDIT final approach. Simple, but not exacly elegant. In the long run you are probably better off using ClickOnce.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        IniParser parser = new IniParser(SupportingClass.AssemblyDirectory + "settings.ini");
        string exe_location = parser.GetSetting("ApplicationToRun", "App");

           string fullName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
        string myName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullName).ToLower();
        if (exe_location != myName)
        {
            string arguments = "";
            foreach (var item in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
            {
                arguments+=item+' ';
            }
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + exe_location))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process starter = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exe_location, arguments);
                return;
            }
        }
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new DbImporting());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should run new copy of the exe by `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` and `return` from current exe instance

Comment: @pm100: was that edit really neccessary? There are more things that you could have edited in this question and title.

Comment: Load an assembly from a dll, don't try to modify the .exe.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can't change it - you're already running the exe! Instead, you need to use some bootstrapper. @agent5566's solution is pretty good - it means you will have the bootstrapper as part of the actual application; the con being that the exe will have to be loaded in memory just to be shut down a few microseconds later :)

The easiest way IMO would be to simply make your link to a `bat` file, rather than the actual application executable. This way, you can change the `bat` whenever you like, and point it to the (currently) correct executable.

The `bat` file would of course have just a single line:

```
@start myApp_v2.exe
```

If you're bothered by the opening command window, just make sure the shortcut is set to launch the window minimized.

However, do note that it's generally not a good idea to develop applications like this in .NET. .NET applications have security settings, and the default is not to allow applications run from a network drive to run with full trust privileges (your application probably isn't going to work). Have you considered using e.g. ClickOnce? It handles the updates automatically for you as well, pretty handy :)

Comment: I've read about ClickOnce, this will probably be the way I'm gonna treat future releases. 
For now I think I'll use agent5566's approach - I don't mind it being closed few microseconds later, this is fairly lightweight application.